# jQuery - How to stop Element Floating

Tags: javascript

I am using this piece of javascript which I found on the net. It works wonderfully well. My problem is this.

The element floats up and down as the piece of code dictates. What I want to do is just have it float down and then stop. I don't know where to put the stop() function. Or if I have to use this function at all. I will be uploading the website in the next couple of days but in the meantime if anybody has a solution before I do so then I would be grateful for your help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function antiGrav(ele) { // anti-gravity floating on an element ;)
var distance = 105;
$(ele).animate({
        'top': "+="+distance+"px"
    },3500,"swing",function(){
        $(ele).animate({
        'top': "-="+distance+"px"
    },3300,"swing",function(){

            antiGrav(ele);
        });
    });

}
antiGrav('#feather');
</script>
```

Comment: Have you made any effort to read and understand the code you've shown?

Answer (score 1):

To just have it float down once and stop, you don't need the recursive function or the animation that animates it up again.

```
var distance = 105;
$('#feather').animate({
    'top': "+="+distance+"px"
},3500,"swing");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CRJ9A/)